# Access 2010: Selected record value from subform

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010, subform

Thank you in advance for the help for this problem - it has been driving me mad.

First of all: My question is regarding the how-to here: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp.

I have a form in Access 2010 that contains a subform. The content of the subform is updated with VBA. Everything works great here.

I want to be able to open another form based on the record, that the user has chosen in the subform. This entails knowing the number of the record selected by the user. To start with, I just what the ID of the chosen record to be written into a normal textbox in the form.

I found the solution in the above-metioned link. It says:

> "To reference a value in a subform, use the following syntax for the
>   text box's Control Source property:
>
> =[subFormName].[Form]![ControlName]"

It works perfectly in their example (I have downloaded the .mdb and it works!), but when I try, the "[Form]" is not an option. And so, I cannot get it to work!

I tried in their .mdb as well, and I cannot chose [Form] either, so as soon as I change the control source property of the textbox, it stops working. I have tried with [.Formula] instead, but nothing (link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL121.png)

What could be the problem? Maybe language settings?

Thank you so much in advance.

M.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it's different in Access 2010 but as you can see below, for Access 2007 :

[image: referencing a subform control]

You can directly refer to a control in the Expression Builder. Just :

a) expand your form name on the left frame

b) select your subform name on the left frame

c1) If you want to refer to a specific control (i.e. a text box) simply select it from the middle frame (double click on it)

c2) If you want to refer to a form property (i.e. the subform's filter) select the  tag in the middle frame, and the corresponding property in the right frame

c3) If you want to refer to an item of the subform's recordset, use the  tag in the middle frame and select the item from the right frame

It should all be there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it. I was not aware that I could chose it from the Expression Builder, but of course! Unfortunatly, the problem persists as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/nq3OpFN.png?1 I am simply not able to create the correct expression, it seems. I have tried in the Access database that's on here: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp as well, and it's the same problem.

Comment: I notice that on the left frame, the form's name is `frmMaster`, not `subMaster`. Not sure if that is linked to your problem. In either case, have tried writing the text? it should be something like `[frmMaster]![Form]![txtID]` or `[frmMaster]![Formular]![txtID]`. I am guessing towards the first case, because even in my native language for Access, the syntax didn't change, it worked written in english.

Comment: I am so sorry, but no, that does not work :( (neither the first or the second example). I don't get the syntax error, but it doesn't work: http://i.imgur.com/T9lcKlG.png?1 I am very grateful that you are taking the time to help me on this. If you have time, could you please try to see, if you are allowed/able to chose [Form] in the expression? The thing is.. The .adb is "born" with that expression (=[subMaster].[Form]![txtID]) and works perfectly, but if I just delete the expression and add it again, it doesn't. There MUST be some language settings, no?

Comment: I noticed that in the example in the .mdb file, the Subform's name is indeed subMaster. When referencing a form located in a form, you must indeed use the name assigned to it in the parent form (it's the control name). Click on the subform and in the properties tab check for its name. Try it once again as `[subMaster]![Form]![txtID]`. If that gets you nowhere, then I'm as puzzled as you are :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not work. But thank you so much for trying so far, it's very kind of you, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting up your question in case it gets noticed by another. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much; i would love to upvote your answer (because it might help others) but I don't have enough points. I'll better start helping others :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the control through VBA in a slightly different manner.  The forms show up as classes with `Form_` in front of them (which is nice because you get to use intellisense).  So your syntax would be similar to the following:

```
Form_Formname.Controls("ControlName").Value
```

That should get you the value of the control on the selected record.  I realise this is pretty old, but I was looking for the answer to this very question, and was able to figure it out on my own with a little experimentation.